# How to linearize membership in a finite set

Tags: modeling, linearization

Given finite set $S$ and variable $x$, how do I linearize the set membership constraint $x\in S$?

Comment: Based on the timestamps, this question appears to be made as a more generalized response to [this question](https://or.stackexchange.com/q/6543/491).  Very clever and very sly.

Comment: Yes, there were several recent questions related to this.  I didn't find any existing question/answer to reference, so I created one.

Comment: Brilliant.   Very useful for future visitors.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, some special cases:

- If $S=\{c\}$, fix $x=c$.
- If $S=\{0,1\}$, declare $x$ to be binary.
- If $S=\{a,b\}\not=\{0,1\}$, introduce binary variable $y$ and impose linear constraint $x=a(1-y)+by$.
- If $S=\{a,a+c,a+2c,\dots,a+kc\}$, introduce integer variable $y\in[0,k]$ and impose linear constraint $x=a+cy$.  (The previous bullet is the special case $c=b-a$ and $k=1$.)

Otherwise proceed as follows.

---

For each $s\in S$, introduce a binary variable $y_s$.  Impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_{s\in S} y_s &= 1 \tag1 \\
\sum_{s\in S} s y_s &= x \tag2
\end{align}
Constraint $(1)$ chooses exactly one $s$ with $y_s=1$, and constraint $(2)$ forces $x=s$ for that $s$.

---

Alternatively (if your modeling language does not allow arbitrary index values), let $I=\{1,\dots,|S|\}$ for 1-based indexing or $I=\{0,\dots,|S|-1\}$ for 0-based indexing, with $S=\{s_i: i \in I\}$.
For each $i\in I$, introduce a binary variable $y_i$.  Impose linear constraints
\begin{align}
\sum_{i\in I} y_i &= 1 \tag3 \\
\sum_{i\in I} s_i y_i &= x \tag4
\end{align}
Constraint $(3)$ chooses exactly one $i$ with $y_i=1$, and constraint $(4)$ forces $x=s_i$ for that $i$.

Comment: For set S, would it be more accurate if it was defined as $S = \{s_i: s_i = ord(i), i \in I \}$ ?

Comment: No, the relationship between $s_i$ and $i$ is instead $\text{ord}(s_i)=i$.

Comment: For case 4 in your special cases, shouldn't "...introduce integer variable $y \in [0,k]$..." instead be "...introduce integer variable $y \in \{0,1,\dots,k\}$..."? I initially read "$y \in [0,k]$" as "$0 \leq y \leq k, y \in \mathbb R$".

Comment: @mhdadk Yes, that is equivalent. “Integer” implies intersection with $\mathbb{Z}$.