# Creating discrete variables in Gurobi

Tags: optimization, gurobi

I am currently working on a project and I want to create a (multiple) decision variable in Gurobi that can only take discrete values with a pre-defined step-width (e.g. 0, 5, 10, ...).

I am currently using the command:

`capacity = m.addVars(locations, lb=0.0, name="capacity")`

However, this command only produces continuous results. I know that by including the optional aspect `vType = ...` you can define binary variables for example. Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything to extract discrete variables with a pre-defined step-width.

Comment: If your set is finite, you might be interested in https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6545/how-to-linearize-membership-in-a-finite-set  If you literally want all nonnegative multiples of $5$ (with no upper bound), take $x=5y$, where $y$ is a nonnegative integer variable.

Comment: Cross Posted on SO:  [Creating discrete variables in Gurobi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73183958/8239061)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `vType=GRB.INTEGER` to specify a discrete variable. A minimum working example will look as follows:

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB


model = gp.Model()
capacity = model.addVars(locations, vType=GRB.INTEGER, name="capacity")
```

---

**Edit**: as mentioned by @Sune, you can get a variable that can only assume values of a multiple of 5 as follows:

```
model = gp.Model()
capacity_count = model.addVars(locations, vType=GRB.INTEGER, name="capacity_count")
capacity = model.addVars(locations, name="capacity")

# Force multiple of 5
model.addConstrs(capacity[l] == 5*capacity_count[l] for l in locations)
```

Note that `capacity` can be a left as a continuous variable, as the constraint forces it to be integer.

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for answering! Using your working example, the values of the decision variable are all with the step-width 1. My question might be a little bit misleading, sorry for that. I want a decision variable, that can only take discrete variables with a pre-defined step-width (like 0, 5, 10, ...).

Comment: @XLF if $z$ is a non-negative integer variable with a "step-width" of 1, then $5z$ is probably what you want.

Comment: Hi Richard and Sune, thanks for answering! It seems to work, so thank you all very much :)