# Optimization solver that satisfies variable values within set membership

Tags: optimization, modeling, solver, ampl, modeling-languages

Is there a solver that can handle an AMPL model of this sort:

```
param max_amt=1;
param min_amt=.05;
set VALUE={min_amt..max_amt by .01}union{0}; # Exact dollar value
var purchase {CUSTOMER} in VALUE; # set membership as opposed to inequality/equality
# Maximize or minimize some utility non-linear function...
```

In other words, a non-linear solver that can satisfy a set membership constrain in continuous domain.

Comment: You are looking for variable purchase to be either 0 or [min, max] value?

Comment: See https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/6545/how-to-linearize-membership-in-a-finite-set for a linearization.

Comment: @Sutanu Yes. Customer may buy in exact dollar amount or not buy at all (=0).

Comment: @wanderinganon Ok, then you can use the answer below or the answer in the link above. Both are the same, it forces the purchase to choose from a set which includes 0, onwards. You can easily generate such a set in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MINLP (Mixed-Integer Non-Linear Problem) solvers can process the optimization predicate of the question I asked of which Bonmin and Couenne are two [FOSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_and_open-source_software) examples, both natively supported in AMPL.

For such a solver the example stated can more suitably be expressed as:

```
param max_amt=1;
param min_amt=.05;
var purchase {CUSTOMER} in interval [min_amount,max_amt] union {0};
```

rounding `purchase[]` as `round(purchase[],2)` wherever it is inputted.

This so far has been the most efficient, least computationally intensive, remedy among the answers I've come across and won't lead to software crash as easily when the range between `min_amt` and `max_amt` enlarges.

Answer (score 1):

AMPL automatically linearizes `var purchase {CUSTOMER} in VALUE;` where `VALUE` is a set of numbers. The linearization creates some binary (zero-one) variables, so you need a solver that can handle such variables.

However, due to the limited precision of floating-point arithmetic in the computer, sets of fractional values like `{min_amt..max_amt by .01}` are problematical. Here's a simplified example of one kind of unexpected result: If you define

```
param min_amt := 0.05;
ampl: param max_amt := 0.22;
ampl: set VALUE = {0} union {min_amt..max_amt by .01};
```

then using AMPL's `display` command, you can look at the members of the set `VALUE`:

```
ampl: display VALUE;
set VALUE :=
0                      0.1                    0.16
0.05                   0.11                   0.16999999999999998
0.060000000000000005   0.12000000000000001    0.18
0.07                   0.13                   0.19
0.08                   0.14                   0.2
0.09                   0.15000000000000002    0.21000000000000002;
```

The number 0.22 is not in the set! This problem is really due to the use of `by .01`. The number .01 cannot be represented exactly in the computer, so when .01 is repeatedly added to `min_amt`, there is some imprecision in the results. In this example, when .01 is added to the previous value 0.21000000000000002, the result is 0.22000000000000003, which not included in the set because it is greater than `max_amt`. To be sure that you do not run into this and similar problems, you can instead define `VALUE` by a series of integers that are each divided by 100:

```
param min_amt := 5;
param max_amt := 22;
set VALUE = {0} union setof {i in min_amt..max_amt} i/100;
```

Then the members of `VALUE` are as expected:

```
ampl: display VALUE;
set VALUE :=
0      0.06   0.08   0.1    0.12   0.14   0.16   0.18   0.2    0.22
0.05   0.07   0.09   0.11   0.13   0.15   0.17   0.19   0.21;
```

When `VALUE` is defined in this way, the linearization of `var purchase {CUSTOMER} in VALUE;` will add some binary variables to your problem, but it will not change the members of `VALUE` -- they will still be fractional, and the values of the variable `purchase` will be fractional.

If you use this approach and still get crashes, you may want to report an example to the [AMPL forum](https://discuss.ampl.com/).

Comment: By " automatically linearizes  `var purchase {CUSTOMER} in VALUE`" you mean the set can't be expressed in reals because AMPL turns them into integers? Your proposed solution does work for me in AMPL so long as the solver is of the kind that admits _mixed-integer_ problem statements (e.g. Couenne). However, the wider the range between `min_amt` and `max_amt` (the cardinality of the set) the higher the chance the solver will crash with some exit code on my system.

Comment: I rewrote the explanation so that it uses a set of reals. You just need to change `max_amt` to 100 or whatever value you want. By "automatically linearizes" I mean that AMPL constructs an equivalent problem that replaces the requirement `var purchase {CUSTOMER} in VALUE` by an equivalent statement using some extra binary variables and a linear constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Define a set like $I= \{0,5,6,...100\}$ and a binary $z_i$.
Add constraints:
$ \sum_{i\in I} iz_{i,k} = 100p_k$ where $p$ is purchase variable for k customers
$ \sum_{i\in I} z_{i,k} = 1$
Above 2 will enforce purchase variable $p$ to choose from the set I

Or
Depending upon objective (if it's linear) you may choose purchase variable $p$ as belonging to domain non-negative integer $Z$ and with a binary $z_{k}$ you can have pair of constraints for all $k$ customers
$100*0.05z_{k} \le p_k \le 100z_k$.
This bounds in non-continuous 0 or $[5,...100] $